# Проблема с Java классом| vovlo| NullPointers

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть java class файл vovlo.java, он ниже

> vovlo.java

```
 package My_classes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author Администрация
 */
public class vovlo {

    @FXML TextArea textArea;
    private String ff;

 public void setTextfromFolder(String ff){
     this.ff = ff;
         File fileFOL = new File(ff);
  try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fileFOL).useDelimiter("\n+");
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            if (s.hasNextInt()) { // check if next token is an int
                textArea.appendText(s.nextInt() + "\n "); // display the found integer
            } else {
```

> ОШИБКА NULL ---

```
   textArea.appendText(s.next() + " "+"\n"); // ERROR
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }; 
        }`
```

Я хочу чтобы файл List при выполнении if запускал этот класс, и я мог изменяя только путь в файл в виде String ff ужать количество строк. Если я просто в if ставлю текст из класса - все работает.

> List

```
    @FXML public void GetDataFromTXT(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException {
        LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();    
        int year = currentTime.getYear();
        String dada = "DADA";
        String DAY = (String)Textday.getText();





    if(DAY.equals("1") & MonChoose.getValue().toString().equals("January")){

      vovlo koko = new vovlo();
```

> (ОШИБКА NULL) 36-- ниже

```
koko.setTextfromFolder("./src/yourDATA/2017/JANUARY/1 JANUARY.txt");//ERROR
        };  
        }}
```

> Ошибка

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at My_classes.vovlo.setTextfromFolder(vovlo.java:36)
    at My_classes.List.GetDataFromTXT(List.java:94)
    ... 58 more
```

Это все связано с FXML файлом

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="298.0" prefWidth="406.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="My_classes.List">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="Textday" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="41.0" onAction="#GetDataFromTXT" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="30.0" />
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="MonChoose" layoutX="40.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="109.0" />
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" layoutX="149.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="257.0" />
      <Button fx:id="close3" layoutX="-1.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#close3" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="30.0" text="Button" />
      <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Enter the day below" />
      <Button fx:id="But" layoutX="46.0" layoutY="109.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#GetDataFromTXT" text="Button" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
   </padding>
   <rotationAxis>
      <Point3D />
   </rotationAxis>
   <opaqueInsets>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="13.0" right="12.0" top="11.0" />
   </opaqueInsets>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Я ввожу в Textday(TextField) число 1 и выбираю в MonChoose(ChoiceBox) месяц January нажимаю кнопку But(Button) и текст с файла  1 JANUARY должно появится в textArea

Comment: Наверное тут без 100 грамм не разберешь.

Comment: Я только дам пару советов: 1) если вы хотите, чтобы ваш код кто-нибудь прочитал, придерживайтесь конвенций - писать названия методов и переменных с маленькой буквы, названия классов - с большой, и т. д., Ваш код трудно читать. 2) Старайтесь сами локализовать свою проблему и воспроизвести ее в маленьком фрагменте кода, и этот фрагмент и помещайте тут. Тогда намного больше шансов будет, что кто-то прочитает и ответит.  Мало у кого есть время и желание читать простыни кода без крайней необходимости. См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 36 строка класа `volvo`, обект равен `null`, что это за строка?

Comment: vovlo.textArea там null, его никто не засеттил, т.к. экземпляр класса vovlo создается через new, а не через FXMLLoader (судя по аннотации @FXML )

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильный контроллер в `fxml` файле, а именно `fx:controller="My_classes.List"`. Измените на `My_classes.volvo`, аннотация `@FXML` работает в контроллере.
[Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь.